# Cross reference and caption not working in Rmd file

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex, caption

Can anyone help me understand how to write my header so that the figure caption and cross reference works?

I am practicing making captions and cross references to a simple plot in my Rmd file. I understand that to do so, I should add to my header: "output: bookend::pdf_document2" and "fig_caption = yes". Then, to a chunk called myfigure, I should add "fig.cap = "\label{fig:myfigure} My caption". To cross reference this figure I should write in the text "@ref(fig:myfigure)". My code is below. It won't knit because the formatting of the header is wrong.

````
---
title: "knit"
author: "Chase Hommeyer"
date: "4/1/2019"
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
  toc: true
  fig_caption: yes
---

```{r myfigure, fig.cap = "\\label{fig:myfigure} My caption"}
plot(pressure)
```

My plot is called \@ref(fig:myfigure).
````

Then, I tried deleting the whitespace before toc and fig_caption, and it knit, but no caption appeared, and the text literally printed "@ref(fig:myfigure)" instead of a cross reference. The header I tried is here:

```
---
title: "knit"
author: "Chase Hommeyer"
date: "4/1/2019"
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
toc: true
fig_caption: yes
---
```

I also tried adding "pdf_document:" to the header, but the same issue of no caption and the cross reference being literally "@ref(fig:myfigure)". This header I tried is here:

```
 ---
title: "knit"
author: "Chase Hommeyer"
date: "4/1/2019"
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    fig_caption: yes
---
```

Can anyone help me understand how to write my header so that it works?

Answer (score 3):

use `\ref{fig:myfigure}` instead of `\\@ref(fig:myfigure)`

See [RStudio Community Post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/cross-reference-problem-relevant-to-figures-only/78432)

Comment: This is very important answer. This solved almost all my problem. This is solution that does not show up in google.

Answer (score 2):

You have a wrong YAML header and some wrong understanding of referencing. I used this RMD file:

````
---
title: "knit"
author: "Chase Hommeyer"
date: "4/1/2019"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: true
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r myfigure, fig.cap = "My caption"}
plot(pressure)
```

My plot is called Figure \@ref(fig:myfigure).
````

First, break the line after `output` in the header. The whitespaces are very important in the YAML header!

Then, read the bookdown manual:

> The label of a figure environment is generated from the label of the code chunk, e.g., if the chunk label is foo, the figure label will be `fig:foo` (the prefix fig: is added before foo). To reference a figure, use the syntax, where label is the figure label, e.g., `fig:foo`.

To reference your plot with the chunk name "myfigure", just write `\@ref(fig:myfigure)`. The caption of the figure can be set via `fig.cap` in the chunk options.