# Referencing to figures in RMarkdown does not work

Tags: r, reference, r-markdown, output, bookdown

First, I make two Waffleplots (I think I did it with ggplot)

```
(...)
waffle_school <- make_waffle(schoolsoort, StudentId)

(...)
waffle_bench <- make_waffle(schoolsoort, benchStudentId)
(...)
```

using some function:

```
make_waffle <- function(variableCol, uniqueIdentifiers, numberRowsWaffle = 5, deleteZeros=1) {
(...)  
 waffle <- waffle(categ_table, colors = Kleuren_schoolsoort[names(Kleuren_schoolsoort) %in% names(categ_table)], rows = numberRowsWaffle) + 
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") + colScale #+ guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)) 
  return(waffle)
}
```

Then I actually show the plots at some point in the text

```
{r Waffleplot-school, fig.height = 2.5, fig.margin=TRUE, fig.cap="\\textcolor{TIGcaptioncolor}{Leerlingen per schoolsoort 21/22 op jullie school}"}
  waffle_school
```

and

```
{r Waffleplot-landelijk, fig.height = 2.5, fig.margin=TRUE, fig.cap=cap1}
  waffle_bench
}
```

which I later want to refer to in my text, by saying:
"In Figure \ref{fig:Waffleplot-school} you can see (..) and in Figure \ref{fig:Waffleplot-landelijk} you see (...)."

This leaves me with question marks in the actual reference in de pdf. By the way, I use pdflatex as a renderer.

Also, this is a part of the yaml header that my main Rmd file has, which I run from another R file.

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
    keep_tex: true
    fig_caption: yes
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    extra_dependencies: ["flafter"]
```

then, I call the Rmd file with the pictures and text (incl. references) in it, which has the following header:

```
---
title: "SchoolInBeeld"
author: "Marja"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
bookdown::pdf_document2
---
```

I have seen the notation \@ref{}, which yielded the exact reference latex call instead of the reference itself: "\ref{fig:Waffleplot-school}". Also, I have visited many questions on this, like

- [Cross reference not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55468806/cross-reference-and-caption-not-working-in-rmd-file) here, outputting in bookdown::pdf_document2 as suggested here, did not help. I changed it back to pdf_document.
- [cross reference in Rmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45018180/cross-reference-to-figure-in-r-markdown-with-html-output-is-not-working)

I feel like the output format is the problem though. Something like me trying to use bookdown things but cannot figure out how to call that package.

FYI, I am fluent in Latex, but relatively new to R.

Comment: By the way, I also used lualatex as a Latex engine, but it messed up my whole 'look and feel' and also did not solve the problem; still two questionmarks.

Comment: Try with this idiom: `\@ref(fig:Waffleplot-school)`

Comment: As stated, I have tried this, but it yields \ref(fig:Waffleplot-school) instead of the reference itself. Do you know why?

Comment: Ok i read @ref without \. Let me try. I remember using pdf_document2 and \@ref idiom worked.

Comment: Oh I see, I think the \ was removed by the stackoverflow renderer, I changed it to \@ but meant that all along.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal complete example of a rmarkdown file with simple plots (say `plot(1:10)`) with reference that showcases the problem?

Comment: Does the problem happen with a single file, or do you need to have your multiple-file inputs?

Comment: @Shafee thanks, I understand that I need to provide a minimal example, but I couldn't manage to do so. I do not really have a clue what my problem is and if I try to reproduce it in small existing datasets, it does not occur.

Comment: @user2554330 Indeed if I make a simpler case with one file only, this problem does not occur. I have worked with referencing in the past and the problem is in the fact that things get complex here with multiple files refering to each other and different output systems.

Comment: I think you need to post a complete example here if you want help.  Here's what I'd suggest:  1.  Keep the main file and the single file with the reference that doesn't work.  Delete the lines that run the other files.  Make sure you still have the problem.  2.  Delete everything from the two files except the minimal amount to show the error.  3.  Post the two files here, along with a description of how you run them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this:

```
---
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    number_sections: true
    keep_tex: true
    fig_caption: yes
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    extra_dependencies: ["flafter"]
```